# ng-bootstrap not working in dropdown in angular

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I want to use ng-bootstrap in my dropdown but it's not working. I have imported NgbModule in app.module.ts. I have attached images below .

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
```

Organic Shop

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/shopping-cart">Shopping Cart</a>
  </li>
  <li ngbDropDown class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a ngbDropdownToggle class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Username</a>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
      <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/my/orders">My Orders</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/admin/orders">Manage Orders</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/admin/products">Manage Products</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="">Log Out</a>
    </div>

  </li>
```

[Output after the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPpVP.png)

Comment: it would be better if you paste the code than image

Comment: done pasting code.

Comment: What’s not working ? Do you receive error messages ?

Comment: No error messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Module, add ngbmodule as root and also add it to providers.

```
import { NgbModule, NgbActiveModal } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";


   imports: [    
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ],
   providers: [NgbActiveModal],
```